# Making a FlashCard Form In Access 2003

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, random

I would like to make a self-study or 'flash card' type form using MS Access 2003 and could use any advice at all.

I have two text boxes (textQuestion, textAnswer).

I have use two command buttons (cmdQuestion, cmdAnswer).

cmdQuestion would randomly pick a question based off of the primary key (which I left as the auto number feature) when clicked.

cmdAnswer would display the answer when clicked.

The buttons would display their respective fields from the table (QA) I have already made.
[ID, Question, Answer] are the fields.

I am stuck on the randomizing portion. So far I have the following ideas

to make the ID be random I think I would use this

```
Randomize
randomID = Int((x * Rnd) + 1)
```

this part does not work and tells me I canceled previous operation error

```
txtQuestion = DLookup("Question", "QA", randomID)
```

using the below works, but I would like to make the ID portion be randomly selected.

```
 txtQuestion = DLookup("Question", "QA", "ID = 1")
```

(I will manually enter the number in for 'x' based on the last row of my table)

I am really new to access and have not had much use with visual basic in the last ten years. Anything would be appreciated.

---

Part 2. 
(Thank you Tony for helping me solve the first half of my troubles!)

I would like to add a feature to select one table out of however many different topics I might have saved these flashcard tables for. A dropdown menu that lists each table that the command buttons would then use when searching for the question and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `txtQuestion = DLookup("Question", "QA", randomID)` to

`txtQuestion = DLookup("Question", "QA", "ID = " & randomID)`

Comment: Also, you can use `DMax("id", "QA")` to set `x` for you.

Comment: Thank you, Tony, for the help with the ID and excellent advice with the DMax suggestion.